# php limit download connection , restriction

Tags: php, file, download, connection, transfer

i trying to write an script for transferring data with limit with restrictions for premium or free or low loading fast loading and etc

i found this code in internet

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

//1- file we want to serve :
$data_file = "movie.mp4";

$data_size = filesize($data_file); //Size is not zero base

$mime = 'application/otect-stream'; //Mime type of file. to begin download its better to use this.
$filename = basename($data_file); //Name of file, no path included

//2- Check for request, is the client support this method?
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) || isset($HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
$ranges_str = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))? 
$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']:$HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_RANGE'];
$ranges_arr = explode('-', substr($ranges_str, strlen('bytes=')));
//Now its time to check the ranges
if ((intval($ranges_arr[0]) >= intval($ranges_arr[1]) && $ranges_arr[1] != "" &&             
$ranges_arr[0] != "" )
    || ($ranges_arr[1] == "" && $ranges_arr[0] == "")
) {
    //Just serve the file normally request is not valid :(
    $ranges_arr[0] = 0;
    $ranges_arr[1] = $data_size - 1;
}
} else { //The client dose not request HTTP_RANGE so just use the entire file
$ranges_arr[0] = 0;
$ranges_arr[1] = $data_size - 1;
}

//Now its time to serve file
$file = fopen($data_file, 'rb');

$start = $stop = 0;
if ($ranges_arr[0] === "") { //No first range in array
//Last n1 byte
$stop = $data_size - 1;
$start = $data_size - intval($ranges_arr[1]);
} elseif ($ranges_arr[1] === "") { //No last
//first n0 byte
$start = intval($ranges_arr[0]);
$stop = $data_size - 1;
} else {
// n0 to n1
$stop = intval($ranges_arr[1]);
$start = intval($ranges_arr[0]);
}
//Make sure the range is correct by checking the file

fseek($file, $start, SEEK_SET);
$start = ftell($file);
fseek($file, $stop, SEEK_SET);
$stop = ftell($file);

$data_len = $stop - $start;

//Lets send headers

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) || isset($HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 206 Partial Content');
    header('Status: 206 Partial Content');
}
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-type: ' . $mime);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$stop/" . $data_size );
header("Content-Length: " . ($data_len + 1));

//Finally serve data and done ~!
fseek($file, $start, SEEK_SET);
$bufsize = 50;

ignore_user_abort(true);
@set_time_limit(0);
while (!(connection_aborted() || connection_status() == 1) && $data_len > 0) {
echo fread($file, $bufsize);
$data_len -= $bufsize;
usleep(1000);
flush();
}

fclose($file);
```

i have a problem with script execution
t want to create connection limit when i download file with idm
i tried to count execution script run with fopen in text file and stop script  run with exit function and also try class property but doesn't work
i realized everytime idm send request for another connection whole script execute from the begin

this will work but only for the first time, when i click stop and resume again a problem arises

```
$file=fopen('text.txt','wr');
//..... code

if ($count < 6){
exit();
}
```

does anyone have a solution for this problem